# How to use an ion-button with a mat-stepper

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material-stepper

I am using ionic, angular 8, and @angular/material/stepper

I have styling already applied to the ion-button tag (provided by a purchased component library).  I would like to use this stying with for the next button within the map-stepper.

However if I switch the (working) button from

```
<button mat-button margin-top matStepperNext shape="round" button-round fill="outline">{{config.nextButton}}</button>
```

to

```
<ion-button mat-button margin-top matStepperNext shape="round" button-round fill="outline">{{config.nextButton}}</ion-button>
```

The no longer functions to advance the stepper.  Is there a simple way to apply the matStepperNext directive to the ion-button tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just encountered this problem, and here what i found:

In the source code of the `@angular/material/stepper/stepper-button` directive the selector for the directive is `button[matStepperNext]` *(for the "Next" button)*. So we can not simply use `ion-button` and expect it to advance or move back the stepper when clicked: the selector doesn't match.

Source: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/70ff528785cb9abe9f102f19b1ea87caef56a295/src/material/stepper/stepper-button.ts#L14

So let's say I have a stepper called "myStepperInstance", to move forward with my project, I'm thinking about creating a listener that executes `myStepperInstance.next()` or `myStepperInstance.previous()` when we click on an ion-button.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old problem but as I am facing it today.

My solution was to hide the angular button and create a click on it with my ion-button.

**In the html**

```
        <div>
          <button mat-button matStepperNext style="display: none" id="nextFirstStep"></button>
          <ion-button  class="primary-btn" shape="round" expand="block" (click)="nextFirstStep()">Next</ion-button>
        </div>
```

**In the TS**

```
nextFirstStep() {
  document.getElementById('nextFirstStep')?.click()
}
```

If you have a lot of steps, you can improve the method by passing the button id in it, to use it on multiple button.